# How to fix Recursion Function overflow error?

Tags: recursion, stack-overflow, physics

This program is supposed to calculate the varying stopping power as a proton travels through aluminium for 20000 slices of 0.025µm of aluminium. The stopping power changes per slice, so the stopping power and subtraction of energy has to be calculated per slice.

I get a stack overflow error even after attempting to increase the recursive limit. Any assistance would be appreciated! `distance(x,E,n)` has the variables `x` which is the step, `E` which is the energy and `n` which is the stopping power. So `distance(0,13000,0.13124)` is the initial step, energy and stopping power.

This is my code:

```py
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10**9)

def distance(x,E,n): 
    step = x + 1 
    if (step >= 20000):
        return E
    
    energy = E - 0.025 * 1/n #E - distance interval per step * stopping power
    stop = -0.0079199 + 0.040703 * energy**(-0.4) + 0.0022677 * energy**(0.25) + 0.000058309 * energy**(0.8) #1/stopping power
   
    return distance(step,energy,stop)

print(distance(0,13000,0.131234))
```

Comment: You want to recurse 20,000 times? What is the source of your formula?

Comment: The 20 000 recurse is not related to the formula, rather its a requirement to try to minimize the error. I have tried using less steps (2950) and increasing the thickness of the slices but this of course decreases how accurate it is in comparison to the 20000 slices.

Comment: Well, the problem I see is that if you do this with 40 000, you get negative energy, so I have some doubt whether this is the correct formula? You have a source for it?

Comment: The stopping power equation was retrieved from NIST PSTAR and fitted to the function represented by stop (done by Eppacher and Semrad).

Comment: Source: C. Eppacher, D. Semrad, Determination of stopping power for ions by backscattering from thin
targets, Nucl. Instr. Meth. B 35 (1988) 109-117.

Comment: OK, so I cannot verify it online. All I can say, is that it doesn't work out to a logical value when doing this 40,000 times instead of 20,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurring with a depth of 20000 is not reasonable. But as your recursive call comes at the very end, you can just convert this to an iterative solution -- without recursion:

```py
def distance(E, n):
    for _ in range(20000):
        E = E - 0.025 * 1/n #E - distance interval per step * stopping power
        n = -0.0079199 + 0.040703 * E**-0.4 + 0.0022677 * E**0.25 + 0.000058309 * E**0.8 #1/stopping power
    
    return E

print(distance(13000,0.131234))
```

I cannot judge if this formula is correct, but this is the translation of your code from a recursive approach to an iterative approach.

Comment: This code gives me the expected value! Thank you for the assistance, I suppose I overcomplicated my end goal?

Comment: Well in theory your version is equivalent, but the call stack that is available is limited, even when you set it high, there is a limit at the lower level. But as this is a case of a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), it can be done without recursion.